# Windows 10 CPU speed command

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, cpu-architecture

What is the command-line command I could use and get the CPU speed specifications? If there are options to also get other CPU specs I could use that too if someone could explain it to me.

Answer (score 2):

`systeminfo` command offers various system specifications along with cpu name and clock speed.

Answer (score 1):

try wmic cpu at the command line or in PowerShell. I found this command most useful and readable:
   wmic cpu list full /format:hform
You have to cut'n'paste the output into a text file and save it as an html document, then open it in your favorite web browser, but you can easily see and interpret the results. Here's a (partial) screen cap:

[image]